# error in .htaccess file and website stops working

Tags: .htaccess

.htaccess file :

```
# Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /
```

when i added this line :
`Options -Indexes` to htaccess file , the site Stopped working
please advice and thanks

Comment: `Options -Indexes` simply is not valid in `.htaccess` style files. The documentation clearly states that.

Comment: ok do you any way to hide index file from your website ??

Comment: Actually I have to retract my comment. Turns out that _is_ actually valid.

Comment: So I suggest you take a look into your http servers error log file to read what the issue is.

Comment: it does not show any errors , all the proplem here that website does wanna load when i add 'Options -Indexes' in htaccess file

Comment: Please define what "the site Stopped working" or "website does wanna load" means exactly.

Comment: it gives me this error : http://error404.000webhost.com/?

Comment: You get an error 404? Not found? Em... You _do_ realize that the option you add to the `.htaccess` style file _prevents_ a request to the base URL or your website to succeed? Exactly _because_ if what that option does?